# Should an entity (like a User) store it's own data?

Tags: php, oop

I've recently learnt OOP in Java and I'm trying to implement what I've learned in my PHP usersystem.

This is my current User class

```
class User {
    public $id;
    public $session;
    public $email;
    public $lastVisit;

    public function __construct($id) {
        $conn = new Conn();
        $array = $conn->ExecuteCmdArray("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '".$id."'");
        $this->session = $array['session'];
        $this->email = $array['email'];
        $this->id = $array['id'];
        $this->lastVisit = $array['last_visit'];
    }
}
```

^ Oh, and am I supposed to execute a SQL to retrieve the data?

However, after taking a look at some examples online, I looked at their `User` class, but realised that in it, only functions like login etc. are present. The attributes in the class are also only the username and password.

Shouldn't it contain all the other variables e.g gender, real_name as well? It seems to me that the user class does not store the userdata, but it's only used for logging in and stuff.

Is this how a User class in PHP usually works - which means my User class is done wrongly?

Comment: This question **is NOT** primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 1):

Well there is no *right way* to design a User class. It depends on the programmers likes, needs, skills and his understanding of OOP and Software-Design.

---

## Seperation of Concerns

> Oh, and am I supposed to execute a SQL to retrieve the data?

It's not recommended. Good software design is about creating decoupled self-contained components.

When designing Software it's a good practice to think out of the box and put yourself into another developers shoes. So if you had a `User` object without knowing what's going behind the scenes. **Would you expect it to fire Database-Queries?** No it's not a Users responsibility to query the database.

**OOP is also about reusability**. If we take your example: *If I threw your `User` class into my own project. It would likely break. You are instantiating a Database Connection directly in the class. What if I had other ways of handling DB access?* Everything would break.

[Seperation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) is the keyword here. And you should adhere to it whenever it's possible.

> However, after taking a look at some examples online, I looked at their User class, but realised that in it, only functions like login etc. are present.

Ask yourself these questions:

1. Should a `User` know how to log in? How his sessions are managed or is this the task of another service maybe?
2. Would you expect that a `User` can log itself in if you didn't know the class?

You see. **By just thinking about the concerns of a class you can eliminate problems in design before they even occur**.

I would not expect my User that he knows how to log in. I rather would expect a service of my application which is explicitly dedicated to that task, to handle it.

```
<?php

$authentication = new UserAuthenticationService();
$authentication->attemptLogin('username', 'password');

if( $authentication->check() )
{
    $user = $authentication->getUser();
    echo $user->username();
}
```

Build your applications so that your classes are as self-contained as possible and only have the dependencies they really need. It's one of the keys of successful software-design.

---

## It's all about your domain

> The attributes in the class are also only the username and password.
>
> Shouldn't it contain all the other variables e.g gender, real_name as well? It seems to me that the user class does not store the userdata, but it's only used for logging in and stuff.

**That depends on your use case**. If you're creating an application where users can anonymously post stories of their last hangover then why would you need a real name there?

If you however are creating some enterprise-business-app-thingy you probably want to store that data. **What data your objects hold is defined by you, and only by you**.

Let's take our hangover-site a step further. I want only minimal information from my users so it could look like this.

```
<?php 

class User {

    private $username;
    private $email;
    private $gender;

    public function __construct( $username )
    {
        $this->username = $username;
    }

    public function username()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    //[...]
    
    public function setUsername( $username )
    {
        $this->username = $username;
    }

    //[...]

}
```

I don't even store the password on my User class because I don't want to. I decide that I will have some kind of persistance manager and an authentication manager which handle those.

```
<?php

$authentication     = new UserAuthenticationService();
$persistanceMapper  = new UserPersistanceMapper();

$authentication->attemptLogin('username', 'password');

if( $authentication->check() )
{
    // Let's rename the User just for fun
    $user = $authentication->getUser();
    $user ->setName('Thomas');
    $persistanceMapper->persist( $user );
}
```

It really depends on your likes. But what I wanted to show in the first place is, that I have objects that do only the thing(s) that they are **responsible for**, or **supposed to do**

- The `User` is able to alter it's own state and is able to provide me with it's data. But he does not know anything about the database.
- `UserPersistanceMapper` knows how to persist a User (in a database or wherever it's supposed to)
- `UserAuthenticationService` knows how a users session needs to be handled

I don't have **the one object that handles all of it**. Instead we have self-contained objects here that are together handling our stuff.

---

## It all comes down to your likes

> Is this how a User class in PHP usually works - which means my User class is done wrongly?

Eventually there is no right and no wrong. If you want to roll that way, do it! You may gain an initial time boost if you are not thinking about design. That may be okay for simple projects that are not hard to maintain.

At the time you are building larger applications however, it's always good to reflect on your own code.

Keep in mind:

- Try to put yourself into some other developers shoes while designing your application
- Visualize how objects are connected to each other **before** you start coding
- Try to keep your classes as self-contained as possible (pass eventual dependencies from the outside)
- Get stuff done! If you can't come up with a clean way to do something: **Just make it work**. **Refactor things later.** But make sure you have a **periodic refactoring cycle**. Don't put stuff aside and think "Yeah... whatever I'll do this later". You will end up with a lot of [Code Smells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) this way.

## Further reading

- [Seperation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)
- [PHP: The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/)
- [SOLID Principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29)

Comment: Have a +1, although some criticism: You should remove the setter on `User` because the object should enforce every user to have a username via it's constructor signature. Username should be `getUsername()`. Also, I disagree with "making it work" then refactoring. If you do that in business you end up with legacy code because it was left as "just working". It's best to think of the right design as you're going through and factor that into the overall time/cost estimate. Other than that, it's a nice start.

Comment: Hey Jimbo thanks for reading through and for your criticism. Yep stupid me, you're absolutely right about setting the username in the constructor. About the `get` prefix. It comes down to preferences here I think. Technically `getUsername()` would be better here but from a semantic point of view I like it more without prefix.

Comment: About the refactoring: What I meant with it, is that one should have refactoring iterations. You write bad code? You put it on your todo and on the next refactoring cycle you fix that. I did not want to say that one should just write sloppy code and say: "Yeah I will do it later ... or never". I will clarify that a bit more.

Thanks @Jimbo

Answer (score 0):

The drawback with the way you made your user class is when you manage lists of users, or process things about lots of users at a time you have to move around all this extra user data, whereas sometimes you would only need it's id, and email.

We can use two or more classes! In your exemple there would be a minimal `User` class, with very minimal attributes and functions, and a `Full_User` class, extending the first one.

```
class User {
    public $id;
    public $email;
    public function __construct($array) {
        $this->email = $array['email'];
        $this->id = $array['id'];
    }
}

class Full_User {
    public $session;
    public $lastVisit;
    public function __construct($array) {
        $this->session = $array['session'];
        $this->lastVisit = $array['last_visit'];
        parent::__construct($array);
    }
}
```

I'd suggest passing the array of properties to the constructor instead of executing the statement. It will allow creating objects from some other data then a database.

```
$id = 12;
$conn = new Conn();
$minimal_array = $conn->ExecuteCmdArray("SELECT id,mail FROM user WHERE id = '".$id."'");
$full_array = $conn->ExecuteCmdArray("SELECT id,mail,session,lastVisit FROM user WHERE id = '".$id."'");
$user_for_listing = new User($minimal_array);
$full_user = new Full_User($full_array);
```